# Counting with MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to count an Int in a MySQL Update Query?

Currently i have

```
UPDATE mails SET uid = 4275
```

and i want something like

```
UPDATE mails SET uid = (4275++)
```

Comment: What did you try? UPDATE mails SET uid = (uid+1)?

Comment: Where is the value that you're assigning to `uid` set? Do you simply want to increment it from 4275 through all records?

Comment: I didn't tried anything... Your code would look like: UPDATE mails SET uid = 4275+1 for me, but it will just add "4276" to every entry...

Comment: Yes, simply counting from 4275 on...

Comment: You most likely would like to add a where clause too, to prevend updating all rows in that table.

Comment: Do you have to set that 4275 each time? Or only once?

Comment: First row 4275, second 4276, third 4277 and so on... thats what i mean...

Comment: What do you mean by "*first row*", "*second*", "*third*" and so on?  SQL tables are unordered.

Comment: I just mean that it should count from 4275 and increase for each line +1

Comment: Only the first, my start-index is 4275.

Comment: You misunderstand me.  SQL tables are *unordered*.  It is meaningless to talk about "*the first*" record without also specifying an ordering over your dataset.  So, how do you define the sort order?  Which record is "*first*"?  Which is "*second*"?  Etc.

Comment: Thats not necessery. i want to order it with the help of this uid which i want to generate. There is no need for an exact order.

Comment: Then I'd go with [@Anshu's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12778025/623041), below.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to do something like this?

```
SELECT @i:=425;

UPDATE mails SET uid = @i:=@i+1;
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to use `SET @i:=4275;` initially, rather than `SELECT` - but otherwise (now that the OP has clarified that order is unimportant), I agree with this answer.  +1

Answer (score 1):

If you need to update the table so that increment each `uid` with 1 then you can do this:

```
   UPDATE mails 
   SET uid = uid + 1;
```

But if you need to increament each value `uid` by an incremental value try this:

```
SET @counter = 0; 
UPDATE mails m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *, (@counter := @counter +1) as counter
    FROM mails
) m2 ON m1.uid = m2.uid
SET m1.uid = m1.uid + m2.counter
```

And if you want to count from 4275 on, just set the counter to `SET @counter = 4275`

Comment: Your second code is what i need, but it tells me [Err] 1 - near "SET": syntax error

Comment: `SET @counter = 4275; 
UPDATE mails m1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *, (@counter := @counter +1) as counter
    FROM mails
) m2 ON m1.uid = m2.uid
SET m1.uid = m1.uid + m2.counter`

Comment: The first. I forgot to say its maybe SQLite. Maybe SQLite can't do @counter?

Comment: @Styler2go It is working fine [See this demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58f89/1)

Comment: @Styler2go Sorry but you have to see the right syntax for the `SET` in sqlite in your case. Please tag it with the `SQLITE` tag.

Comment: I am using your code in MySQL now. I added a Where to the query but now it tells me: 
`UPDATE ps_emails m1 INNER JOIN (
SELECT * , (
@counter := @counter +1
) AS counter
FROM ps_emails
)m2 ON m1.uid = m2.uid
SET m1.uid = m1.uid + m2.counter WHERE timetsamp =0`
Error: `#1054 - Unknown column 'timetsamp' in 'where clause' `

Comment: @Styler2go do you have a column named `timestamp` in your table?

Comment: @Styler2go Try to quote it using  ```timetsamp```' = '0' because you can't use it unquoted.

Comment: `#1052 - Column 'timestamp' in where clause is ambiguous` and my Query is: `UPDATE ps_emails m1 INNER JOIN (
SELECT * , (
@counter := @counter +1
) AS counter
FROM ps_emails
)m2 ON m1.uid = m2.uid
SET m1.uid = m1.uid + m2.counter WHERE `timestamp` = 0`

Comment: @Styler2go you have to alias it to be unambiguous so that mysql knows is it from `m1` or `m2` like WHERE m1.`timestamp`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17691/discussion-between-styler2go-and-mahmoud-gamal)

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE mails SET uid = uid + x

x meaning any number

I didn't get your question properly but I am just answering as I understood

UPDATE mails SET uid = uid + 1

i.e to increment current uid by the lastuid + 1

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE mails SET uid = uid +1` will add 1 to every uid column.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
UPDATE mails SET uid = uid+1
where uid = 4275
```

Answer (score -1):

You can keep your own counter

```
declare @curr_uid integer; 
SET @curr_uid = 4275; -- initial uid

update mails
set uid = @curr_uid , @curr_uid = @curr_uid + 1
```

Comment: You can't use `DECLARE` outside of stored programs; nor can a user-defined variable be the target of the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: Create store procedure and execute it, and you can have user-defined variable in set clause of an update statement. At least it worked when I tested on SQL Server 2008. I don't have mysql here but I think it should work as well. You can test it if you wish.